# Recommended way to shade an area of graph2d between custom time bars

Tags: vis.js

I am looking for a recommended way of accomplishing the following use case:

In a graph2d, I want the user to beable to select a portion of the timeline by using two customTime bars as the endpoints of the selection.  I want to be able to highlight the selected portion of the graph between the two custom bars.

Here is an example of my current implementation: http://jsbin.com/goqekul/3/edit?js,output

This is the code to change the groups of the items:

```
  graph2d.on('timechange', (properties) => {
  var start = moment(graph2d.getCustomTime('start'));
  var end = moment(graph2d.getCustomTime('end'));
     var itemUpdates = _.map(_.range(items.length), (item) => {
     var group;
     if (moment(items[item].x).isBetween(start,end)) {
       group = 1;
     } else if (moment(items[item].x).isSameOrBefore(start)) {
       group = 0;
     } else {
       group = 2;
     }
       var ret = {
         id: item,
        group: group
      };
    return ret;
  });
  dataset.update(itemUpdates);
});
```

When a custom bar moves, it updates the items in the dataset to by in a selected or unselected group to add shading to the graph to highlight the portion between the two bars.

This seems to get slow for many data points, however. Is there a recommended or better solution to this problem that doesn't use groups, or an entirely different approach?

Comment: Show some code and explain as clearly as possible what you want it to do.

Comment: @jdv updated the question, thanks for your feedback!  Happy to refine if my goals are still unclear.